# RabbitMQ Subscriber does not receive messages

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I am trying to use RabbitMQ for a simple project. While following a tutorial, I found that the queue is showing one unacknowledged message and my subscriber is stuck. The problem occurs when I start the subscriber after starting the publisher.

So it is just like this: If I send messages to queue when subscriber is listening, subscriber can get those messages. But when I start subscriber "after" queue get messages, It just cannot get these messages.

Here is the code I used:

###### Publisher

```cs
using System.Text;
using RabbitMQ.Client;

namespace RabbitMQ.Publisher
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory();

            using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();

            var channel = connection.CreateModel();

            channel.ExchangeDeclare("logs-fanout", durable: true, type: ExchangeType.Fanout);

            Enumerable.Range(1, 50).ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                string message = $"log {x}";

                var messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

                channel.BasicPublish("logs-fanout", "", null, messageBody);

                Console.WriteLine($"Mesaj gönderilmiştir : {message}");
            });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

###### Subscriber

```cs
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;
using System.Text;

namespace RabbitMQ.Subscriber
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory();

            using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();

            var channel = connection.CreateModel();

            var randomQueueName = "log-database-save-queue"; //channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;

            channel.QueueDeclare(randomQueueName, true, false, false);

            channel.QueueBind(randomQueueName, "logs-fanout", "", null);

            channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

            channel.BasicConsume(randomQueueName, false, consumer);

            Console.WriteLine("Loglar dinleniyor...");

            consumer.Received += (object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs e) =>
            {
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Body.ToArray());

                Console.WriteLine("Gelen Mesaj: " + message);

                channel.BasicAck(e.DeliveryTag, false);
            };

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out why the queue behaves in this way and how I can fix it?